# Is "xs:" a built-in prefix in schematron?

Tags: schematron

Is "xs:" a built-in prefix in schematron, or do I have to use ns to link the prefix to the XMLSchema namespace?

Comment: Good question, my guess is it will depend on the used query language and the used Schematron implementation.

Comment: In an XPath 1.0 or XSLT 1.0 based query binding/implementation like https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt-redux-xslt1 I would rather not expect any support or meaningful use of `xs:`.